# Running a WindowsGL MonoGame release on end Machine

Tags: monogame, release

Can anyone tell me what is required of a PC to run a released MonoGame.
I mean what software the PC needs to have installed to run the games.
I have some problems running my released games on other PC's than my developer machine. They simply stops responding when I try to run them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assuming you are using the exact same setup of VS2010/VS2012 as myself.**

Ensure all art/sound/effect assets File Properties are set properly.

*a. Build Action should be set to Content*

*b. Copy To Output Directory should be Copy if newer or Copy Always*

Using VS201X's Publish will provide an easy to use installer.

*a. The Setup.exe file will install .Net4.0 on the users machine if it is missing.*

*b. YourGame'sName.application will install the game.*

User will need to install [OpenAl](http://connect.creativelabs.com/openal/Downloads/oalinst.zip)

Comment: Thx for the reply :) It was the openAL I was missing

Comment: I wonder if you can include OpenAL in your installer?